# spring-repository.xsd imported in spring-ldap-2.x.xsd cannot be found in spring.schemas of spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-ldap, spring-data-commons

**spring-ldap-2.2.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:ldap="http://www.springframework.org/schema/ldap"
           xmlns:repository="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           targetNamespace="http://www.springframework.org/schema/ldap">

    <xs:import namespace="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository"
                schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository/spring-repository.xsd" />

    ......

    <xs:element name="repositories">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexContent>
                <xs:extension base="repository:repositories">
                    <xs:attribute name="ldap-template-ref">
                        <xs:annotation>
                            <xs:documentation>
                                The reference to an LdapTemplate. Will default to 'ldapTemplate'.
                            </xs:documentation>
                        </xs:annotation>
                    </xs:attribute>
                </xs:extension>
            </xs:complexContent>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

**spring.schemas in spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar**

```
https\://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository/spring-repository-1.0.xsd=org/springframework/data/repository/config/spring-repository-1.0.xsd
https\://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository/spring-repository-1.4.xsd=org/springframework/data/repository/config/spring-repository-1.4.xsd
https\://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository/spring-repository-1.5.xsd=org/springframework/data/repository/config/spring-repository-1.5.xsd
https\://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository/spring-repository-1.6.xsd=org/springframework/data/repository/config/spring-repository-1.6.xsd
https\://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository/spring-repository-1.7.xsd=org/springframework/data/repository/config/spring-repository-1.7.xsd
https\://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository/spring-repository-1.8.xsd=org/springframework/data/repository/config/spring-repository-1.8.xsd
https\://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository/spring-repository-1.11.xsd=org/springframework/data/repository/config/spring-repository-1.11.xsd
https\://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository/spring-repository-2.1.xsd=org/springframework/data/repository/config/spring-repository-2.1.xsd
https\://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository/spring-repository.xsd=org/springframework/data/repository/config/spring-repository-2.1.xsd
```

**Specail Case**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:ldap="http://www.springframework.org/schema/ldap"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/ldap http://www.springframework.org/schema/ldap/spring-ldap.xsd">

    <ldap:context-source id="contextSource"
                         url="xxx"
                         base="xxx"
                         username="xxx"
                         password="xxx"/>

    <ldap:ldap-template id="ldapTemplate" context-source-ref="contextSource"/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="xxx"/>

</beans>
```

Exception is thrown when load appContext-ldap.xml as below, additional condition: the network is not reachable.

> 九月 12, 2019 1:55:33 下午 org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager prepareTestInstance
>   严重: Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@3fb6a447] to prepare test instance [liuming.dao.UserDaoTest@47db50c5]
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
>       at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
>       at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
>       at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 673 in XML document from class path resource [appContext-ldap-new.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: http://www.springframework.org/schema/ldap/spring-ldap.xsd; lineNumber: 673; columnNumber: 62; src-resolve: 无法将名称 'repository:repositories' 解析为 'type definition' 组件。
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:399)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:252)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:257)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:124)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:108)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:251)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
>       ... 24 more
>   Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: http://www.springframework.org/schema/ldap/spring-ldap.xsd; lineNumber: 673; columnNumber: 62; src-resolve: 无法将名称 'repository:repositories' 解析为 'type definition' 组件。
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:396)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaErr(XSDHandler.java:4154)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaError(XSDHandler.java:4137)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getGlobalDecl(XSDHandler.java:1684)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDComplexTypeTraverser.traverseComplexContent(XSDComplexTypeTraverser.java:768)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDComplexTypeTraverser.traverseComplexTypeDecl(XSDComplexTypeTraverser.java:315)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDComplexTypeTraverser.traverseLocal(XSDComplexTypeTraverser.java:164)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDElementTraverser.traverseNamedElement(XSDElementTraverser.java:392)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDElementTraverser.traverseGlobal(XSDElementTraverser.java:242)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.traverseSchemas(XSDHandler.java:1439)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.parseSchema(XSDHandler.java:635)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema(XMLSchemaLoader.java:610)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.findSchemaGrammar(XMLSchemaValidator.java:2447)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:1768)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.emptyElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:761)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:351)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2784)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:842)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:771)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:243)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:339)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:76)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadDocument(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:429)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391)
>       ... 37 more

*I think Mybe it's spring-ldap's bug:*

- spring-repository.xsd schemaLocation defined in spring-ldap-2.2.xsd is `http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository/spring-repository.xsd`, but the schemaLocation is defined as `https://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository/spring-repository.xsd` in spring.schemas of spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar.
- one is `http`, other is `https`, not identical.

So when network is not reachable, could not find spring-repository.xsd from local.

github issue link: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ldap/issues/539

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: @M.Deinum  I'm not sure wether it's spring-ldap's bug, I need confirmation.

Comment: Looking at the current ldap.xsd it contains `https` so looks like you are mixing incompatible versions.

Comment: `<xs:import namespace="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository" schemaLocation="https://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository/spring-repository.xsd" />`    spring-repository.xsd is imported in ldap.xsd, the schemaLocation of spring-repository.xsd contains `https`. spring-repository.xsd is stored in spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar, there is no `https` in spring.schemas, could not find the spring-repository.xsd use `https://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository/spring-repository.xsd` in spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar.

Comment: Judging from the fact spring data ldap is part of the release train I doubt it is a bug but rather you using incompatible versions.

Comment: I notice that this problem has be resolved after commit [885ba33#diff-f7f736ab82493822666d805be2d82bbb](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ldap/commit/885ba331acb5382bd973650ac95868d0472afe92#diff-f7f736ab82493822666d805be2d82bbb), but spring-ldap.jar version ≤ 2.3.2.RELEASE in public maven repository still has this problem.

spring-ldap should rebuild jar and distribute it to maven repository.